# How does black rice cook?

Tags: rice

I bought black rice for the first time, and I am unsure what to use it for. It would be helpful if I knew how it behaves when cooked. The info I'm looking for is: (assume fully cooked corns)

1. Stickiness. Do the corns stick to each other, or remain separate?
2. Corn structure. Does it feel mealy, or smooth to the tooth?
3. Hardness. How hard is the fully-cooked grain as compared to other rice types (including wild rice)?
4. General use. I assume it can be used as white rice, so I am not asking you to list how to use it. But are there uses for which it can't be used? Risoto is probably a no-brain example, are there other dishes where the use of black rice will be so bad as to cause the dish to fail?
5. Taste. Is there something very specific about its taste, or is it within the usual variety to be expected from rice?
6. Misc. If there is something important I forgot to include, feel free to include it in your answer.

I already went through Wikipedia and the highest Google results for black rice. I'd like some more information, preferably based on personal experience or not-so-obvious sources.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I used black rice in different recipes. It clearly take longer to cook than normal rice, the grains remain separate and its generally harder than normal rice (I would say something similar to wild rice, but more mealy).
As you said, it's not suitable for risotto per se, but I once made a risotto with normal rice and almost at the end of the cooking I added some (already cooked) black rice, which added a nice color and texture.
The taste is quite strong, so you might want to avoid foods that are too mild in taste. A good combination for me is with peppers, olives and feta cheese, possibly mixed together in a cold rice salad.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I like your idea for adding black rice to a normal risotto.

Answer (score 3):

I don't have a specific answer, but here in Sikkim, India, my mother bought black rice during an agriculture fair. We make pudding by pressure cooking it in water and then adding milk and sugar or jaggery to it, although the latter gives it a chocolate colour and not purply-burgundy one. Pressure cooking only made it custardy, but the grains separate beautifully and we love the chewy, almosty "squeaky" texture.

Comment: Hello minla and welcome to the site. I hope you'll enjoy it here. As you can see, I edited your answer a bit. Don't worry, this is normal if this happens. However, I deleted a question in your answer too, because an answer is not the place to ask an additional question. You can always search the site or ask the question yourself, as a new question.

Comment: @Minla I agree with Mien. You are welcome to post your question separately, it is a good fit for our site, it just shouldn't be posted here, as this space is reserved for answers. Use http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/ask to ask.

Answer (score 1):

Yes to add to :how to use wild and brown rice ,I made 
Spanish rice authnic style , I put oil to get it hot then add brown rice stir in hot oil for 5 minutes then I added wild rice stir on Med heat until the brown rice is very brown . Ain a septette pan add peeled chopped  tomato,  and chopped onions , chicken  bouillon powder stir all these
Ingridents   When veggies are tender set aside, when the rice is really  brown add water and sautéed veggies cook till rice is tender and fluids are almost all  gone . Serve hot ,it takes about 45 minutes to cook or until tender

Comment: To finish the rice kit takes about 45minutes

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. This is kind of confusing; you might want to edit your answer to make it clearer and easier to read.